# Nervous about this application. Could it be Malware? Can i find out?

Tags: malware

[image: Popup I keep randomly getting]

I don't know what is, I won't click it and you can't right-click the link. How can I figure out what it is, and if it is malware how can I identify it as such?

Comment: What browser are you using? And what Ubuntu version? From a first sight, it looks like ScareWare scaring you into installing some fake remedy.

Comment: Would delete/remove that browser and reinstall.  Would also add an adblocker as the first extension on reinstalled browser.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the browser extension "Click & Clean"? This looks like one of their messages to me. Click & Clean offers you to clear your browsing history (cookies, history of visited sites etc.). You can do that automatically, when you exit the browser, and/or by clicking on a button. This message basically tells you "Hey, you haven't cleaned your browsing history in a while, maybe you want to look into doing it now".

Answer (score 0):

You can upload and scan any file to [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload)

You can also do a site search for executable files you might be leary of as well.